# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction on my server

Tags: mysql

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I got this error all the time because the row is already under transaction so what do know?